# Unity2D Snake Game

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I made a snake game in unity but whenever the snake grows the segment that should be added to the snake dissappears when i change the direction and idk why.

Here's the code:

```cs
    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        for (int i = _segments.Count - 1; i > 0; i--)
        {
            _segments[i].position = _segments[i - 1].position;
        }

        this.transform.position = new Vector2(
            Mathf.Round(this.transform.position.x) + sobolan.x,
            Mathf.Round(this.transform.position.y) + sobolan.y
            );

    }

    private void Grow()
    {   
        Transform segment = Instantiate(this.segmentPrefab);
        segment.position = _segments[_segments.Count - 1].position;
        _segments.Add(segment);
    }

    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        if (other.tag == "Food")
        {
            Grow();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Note that using the correct tags is key here. Otherwise people might not see your question ;) (like e.g. me who is watching the Unity3d tag)

Comment: How do you update the position of `_segments[0]`? is that the same as `transform`?

Comment: Hi, thanks for replaying. I think that might be the problem. What should I do?

Comment: Also this is my first time using this platform so I'm not very familiar with it

Comment: Without having your project it is a bit hard to debug this but I would guess somewhere two segments end up on the same position .. as said I don't see you updating the position of the first element `_segments[0]` .. except this equals the object this script is attached to ...

Comment: I know it might be hard for you to tell me what to do exactly without having my project, but can you please just give me an idea, this is my second project in unity, its kind of a homework and I dont know how to fix it.